# AutoHotKey: Move cursor to position step by step

Tags: autohotkey, mousemove

I've been breaking my head around this:
I need to move the cursor from the current position to a new position, step by step, rather than through `MouseMove`, as it is too swift (even with a minimum speed of 100) and smooth (not random enough).

Furthest I have come is this, but I think there must be a much better way:

```
desX = 100 ;new position X
desY = 100 ;new position Y
MouseGetPos, posX, posY
stepX = %desX% - %posX%
stepY = %desY% - %posY%
if(stepX > 0 & stepY > 0)
{
    while(posX < desX & posY < desY)
    {
        Random, randX, -1, 1
        posX := posX + randX
        posX++

        Random, randY, -1, 1
        posY := posY + randY
        posY++

        MouseMove, posX, posY, 100


        MouseGetPos, posX, posY
    }
}
```

This would require a lot of code for every possible direction (e.g. NW, SW, NE, N).

Comment: Trying to make a computer screen look like it's working on itself, for an exhibition. So kind of, yes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest writing a separate function that will make multiple mouse movements that fit within the start and end points.

#### Example

```
gradual_mousemove(end_x,end_y,time=1000,delay=10) {
    ;preserve settings
    original_coordmode := A_CoordModeMouse

    CoordMode, Mouse, Screen
    MouseGetPos, start_x, start_y

    ;compute deltas
    dx := end_x - start_x
    dy := end_y - start_y

    ;delay ms per step
    step_t := time / delay

    original_mousedelay:=A_MouseDelay 
    SetMouseDelay, 0

    loop % step_t
    {
        p := (A_index/step_t)
        step_x := start_x + (p*dx)
        step_y := start_y + (p*dy)
        Click, %step_x%, %step_y%, 0 ;move without clicking

        sleep, %delay%

        ;debug info
        ;ToolTip X: %step_x%  Y: %step_y%  P: %p%  D: %delay%  T: %time%   S: %A_Index% / %step_t%

        MouseGetPos, mx, my
        if ( (mx==end_x) && (my==end_y) )
            break
    }

    ;ensure correct end point
    Click, %end_x%, %end_y%, 0

    ;reset settings
    CoordMode, Mouse, %original_coordmode%
    SetMouseDelay, %original_mousedelay%
}
```

You might have to play around with to get the correct speeds and timings you want. This is just a linear increment example, you could potential change it to use a logarithmic model or what not.